# Do we need a tag entitled language-tests or something similar to it?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have some questions about the minimum language requirements and also the English tests the results of which are required to be sent by students to the universities for their admissions.

We have [toefl](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toefl) and [ielts](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ielts) tags, but regarding the questions which *are* about language testing but not about those two tests, such as

> [Is the Cambridge Certificate of English accepted in US?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30331/is-the-cambridge-certificate-of-english-accepted-in-us)

we don't have a tag to cover questions about language tests and certificates other than toefl or ielts.

Is it a good idea to create a tag entitled [language-tests](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-tests) to cover questions with following scopes and possibly merge the [toefl](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toefl) and [ielts](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ielts) tags into it?

1. Questions about English language tests such as TOEFL, IELTS, FCE, CAE, CPE, etc.
2. Questions about non-English language tests
3. Questions about the English tests which are designed by universities

Answer (score 1):

I am in favor of making [toefl](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toefl) and [ielts](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ielts) synonyms of [language-exams](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-exams).

But, I believe the appropriate way to enact this is to propose it as a [tag synonym](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). If the synonym gets enough upvotes from users, it is activated automatically.

Comment: I just wanted to first ask it here to make sure it is relevant. Because I did not want to propose an irrelevant tag synonym...

Comment: @Enthusiastic I'm not saying that it was inappropriate to bring it up for discussion here, just that the best way to *enact* it would be via tag synonyms.

Comment: OK. I will propose a tag synonym.

Comment: I proposed [tag:ielts] and [tag:toefl] tags as synonyms of the [tag:language-exams] tag. Could you please [up-vote](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) them?